# Is there an API for looking up ENS records?

Tags: etherscan, ens

Currently I'm using this to do ens lookups: https://etherscan.io/enslookup

But is there a public API I can use to do queries to see what each ens goes to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cindercloud has an endpoint you can use for that:
https://rapidapi.com/Qkyrie/api/cindercloud

Comment: API doesn't resolve.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning on using these ENS lookups in a JavaScript / web app, I'd recommend using Ethers.js builtin [ENS lookup functions](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html#ethereum-naming-service) `provider.resolveName(ensName)` and `provider.lookupAddress(address)`.

This doesn't really answer the question regarding a public API, but I generally find using a wrapper preferable to making API calls directly. If you're not creating a JS app, there's probably similar libraries or wrappers around ENS for different languages.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an additional dedicated API endpoint to lookup ens names.
You can use the RPC node endpoint to query ENS. [chainlist.org](https://chainlist.org) maintains a list of RPC endpoints.

Here is sample code:

```
const mainnetProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet-public.unifra.io");
mainnetProvider.lookupAddress('0x378a29135fdFE323414189f682b061fc64aDC0B3'); // this returns ens name
mainnetProvider.resolveName('sandeep45.eth'); // this returns address
```

Full ens lookup documentation is here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--ens-methods